# How can I override few parameter of plugin without editing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Want to override few parameter of plugin without editing it. link for plugin https://www.o2.co.uk/shop/homepage/images/shop15/carousel/js/carousel.jquery.js Can we add another script to override above script object parameter such as displayTime to 1000 & autoStart to false. . I tried $.extend(). but failed. I don't want to make changes in current plugin

```
<script>

(function($,document,undefined) {
$.fn.carousel = function(opts) {
var options = {
   'displayTime': 5000,
   'autoStart': true
};

<----code --->
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it with a function of your own:

```
var oldCarousel = $.fn.carousel; // Need a reference to the original
$.fn.carousel = function(opts) {
  var options = {
    // set your personal defaults here
  };
  if (opts) {
    $.extend(options, opts);
  }
  return oldCarousel.call(this, opts);
};
```

Comment: Thank Mike. but I can not make any change/replace existing code. Have to override this parameter using external code

Comment: @golekunal88 This is external code. You can place this in any of your files.